# How long does it take to set up an I/O controller on PCIe bus

Tags: device-driver, pci-e

Say I have an InfiniBand or similar PCIe device and a fast Intel Core CPU and I want to send e.g. 8 bytes of user data over the IB link. Say also that there is no device driver or other kernel: we're keeping this simple and just writing directly to the hardware. Finally, say that the IB hardware has previously been configured properly for the context, so it's just waiting for something to do.

Q: How many CPU cycles will it take the local CPU to tell the hardware where the data is and that it should start sending it?

More info: I want to get an estimate of the cost of using PCIe communication services compared to CPU-local services (e.g. using a coprocessor). What I am expecting is that there will be a number of writes to registers on the PCIe bus, for example setting up an address and length of a packet, and possibly some reads and writes of status and/or control registers. I expect each of these will take several hundred CPU cycles each, so I would expect the overall setup would take order of 1000 to 2000 CPU cycles. Would I be right?

I am just looking for a ballpark answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ballpark number is correct.

If you want to send an 8 byte payload using an RDMA write, first you will write the request descriptor to the NIC using Programmed IO, and then the NIC will fetch the payload using a PCIe DMA read. I'd expect both the PIO and the DMA read to take between 200-500 nanoseconds, although the PIO should be faster.

You can get rid of the DMA read and save some latency by putting the payload inside the request descriptor.